# BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly alternative to avoid ambiguous properties of derived classes (AmbiguousMatchException)

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'am looking for a solution to access 'flatten' (lowest) properties values of a class and its derived via reflection by property names.

ie access either *Property1* or *Property2* from the *ClassB* or *ClassC* type :

```
   public class ClassA
    {
        public virtual object Property1 { get; set; }

        public object Property2 { get; set; }
    }
    public class ClassB : ClassA
    {
        public override object Property1 { get; set; }
    }
    public class ClassC : ClassB
    {
    }
```

Using simple reflection works until you have virtual properties that are overrired (ie *Property1* from *ClassB*). Then you get a *AmbiguousMatchException* because the searcher don't know if you want the property of the main class or the derived.

Using BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly avoid the AmbiguousMatchException but unoverrided virtual properties or derived classes properties are ommited (ie *Property2* from *ClassB*).

Is there an alternative to this poor workaround :

```
// Get the main class property with the specified propertyName
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = _type.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);

    // If not found, get the property wherever it is
    if (propertyInfo == null)
            propertyInfo = _type.GetProperty(propertyName);
```

Furthermore, this workaround not resolve the reflection of 2nd level properties : getting *Property1* from *ClassC* and *AmbiguousMatchException*  is back.

My thoughts : I have no choice except loop... Erk... ??

I'am open to Emit, Lambda (is the Expression.Call can handle this?) even DLR solution.

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to do this is to enumerate all of the properties and filter out the duplicates.

I'd recommend using a library like [Fasterflect](http://fasterflect.codeplex.com) to do this. It solves the hard problems and gives you a ton of nice features over what you can do with standard reflection.

```
// find properties and remove duplicates higher up the hierarchy
var properties = type.Properties( Flags.ExcludeBackingMembers );
```

Comment: +1 for Fasterflect but I guess it will be less effecient than a emit / expression tree / DLR code ?

Comment: It uses emit under the covers, although not for lookups (since that is not an option).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution with Fasterflect :**

```
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in objType.Properties(Flags.ExcludeBackingMembers | Flags.Public | Flags.Static | Flags.Instance))
{
    FasterflectPropertyValue(propertyInfo.Name, obj);
}

private static object FasterflectPropertyValue(string propertyName, object obj)
{
    return obj.GetPropertyValue(propertyName);
}
```

`Reflection from Class1 - 1 loops :3602674ticks`
`Reflection from Class2 - 1 loops :2940541ticks`
`Reflection from Class3 - 1 loops :1035300ticks`
`Reflection from Class1 - 100 loops :2ms`
`Reflection from Class2 - 100 loops :2ms`
`Reflection from Class3 - 100 loops :3ms`
`Reflection from Class1 - 10000 loops :274ms`
`Reflection from Class2 - 10000 loops :284ms`
`Reflection from Class3 - 10000 loops :295ms`
`Fasterflect from Class1 - 1 loops :44ms`
`Fasterflect from Class2 - 1 loops :2508656ticks`
`Fasterflect from Class3 - 1 loops :2314142ticks`
`Fasterflect from Class1 - 100 loops :3223064ticks`
`Fasterflect from Class2 - 100 loops :5056514ticks`
`Fasterflect from Class3 - 100 loops :5166725ticks`
`Fasterflect from Class1 - 10000 loops :96ms`
`Fasterflect from Class2 - 10000 loops :138ms`
`Fasterflect from Class3 - 10000 loops :162ms`